# How do I implement custom fields without using any plugins?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-type

I am trying to create a member directory and using a custom post type members. I am familiar on how to use the ACF plugin but is there any methods on how to associate a custom field for a specific custom post type to have a simple input box like phone number and address?

Comment: [Custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) are already a build in feature. You just need to add support for it when registering your custom post type ;-)

Comment: Thanks Pieter but is there a way to add a code so we dont have to select the custom field for each adding of a new entry?I'll try Carl's code first to see if that works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use a plugin, you can try implementing a meta box to be associated with that custom post type, This is the code that I use if I want to add a simple input field for a certain post type, in the example below, I assume that the **member_post_type** is your declared post type:

```
function member_add_meta_box() {
//this will add the metabox for the member post type
$screens = array( 'member_post_type' );

foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

    add_meta_box(
        'member_sectionid',
        __( 'Member Details', 'member_textdomain' ),
        'member_meta_box_callback',
        $screen
    );
 }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'member_add_meta_box' );

/**
 * Prints the box content.
 *
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function member_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

// Add a nonce field so we can check for it later.
wp_nonce_field( 'member_save_meta_box_data', 'member_meta_box_nonce' );

/*
 * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
 * from the database and use the value for the form.
 */
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

echo '<label for="member_new_field">';
_e( 'Phone Number', 'member_textdomain' );
echo '</label> ';
echo '<input type="text" id="member_new_field" name="member_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
 function member_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

 if ( ! isset( $_POST['member_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
    return;
 }

 if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['member_meta_box_nonce'], 'member_save_meta_box_data' ) ) {
    return;
 }

 if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
    return;
 }

 // Check the user's permissions.
 if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

 } else {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
 }

 if ( ! isset( $_POST['member_new_field'] ) ) {
    return;
 }

 $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['member_new_field'] );

 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'member_save_meta_box_data' );
```

**Additional Resources for the WordPress Metaboxes:**

please see documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)

Comment: I tried adding your code in my theme's function.php and I have new metabox in my custom post type. Would you happen to know if I can also control s metabox order if it would be displayed first or at the last part?

Comment: @Macorgano Yes, you can. The fifth parameter to `add_meta_box` indicates where you want it to be while the sixth indicates the priority.

You really should check out the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

As I already stated in comments,

> [Custom fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) are already a build in feature. You just need to add support for it when registering your custom post type ;-)

You have two options here:

- When you [register your custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments), simply add `custom-fields` to the `supports` parameter

  Example:

  ```
  add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
  function codex_custom_init() {
      $args = [
        'public' => true,
        'label'  => 'Books',
        'supports' => ['title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields']
      ];
      register_post_type( 'book', $args );
  }
  ```
- You can simply use [`add_post_type_support()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) to add custom fields to your custom post type

  Example:

  ```
  add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_add_custom_fileds_support_for_cpt', 11 );
  function wpcodex_add_custom_fileds_support_for_cpt() {
      add_post_type_support( 'cpt', 'custom-fields' ); // Change cpt to your post type
  }
  ```